# WPF: How to remove handler for Loaded event

Tags: wpf

I try to create a custom control in WPF. In the constructor of my control I register several event handlers:

```
Public Sub New()
    ...
    
    AddHandler MyBase.Loaded, AddressOf Me.OnLoaded
    AddHandler MyBase.SizeChanged, AddressOf Me.OnSizeChanged
    
    ...
End Sub
```

Since I register them in the constructor I thought it would be a good idea to unregister them in the destructor, so I added the appropriate calls there:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    MyBase.Finalize()
    
    ...
    
    RemoveHandler MyBase.Loaded, AddressOf Me.OnLoaded
    RemoveHandler MyBase.SizeChanged, AddressOf Me.OnSizeChanged

    ...
End Sub
```

With the `SizeChanged` event there's no problem, but I get an `InvalidOperationException` when I try to remove the `Loaded` event handler. The exception says: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

I didn't do anything with different threads in this project, so I'm a little bit lost on how to remove the handler for the `Loaded` event again.

Is it ok to remove the handler inside the handling function, since the `Loaded` event is fired only once anyway?

Comment: It is of course ok to remove the Loaded handler in OnLoaded. Did you not try that? It seems however not necessary at all to remove any handlers when the control is destroyed.

Comment: I tried to remove the `Loaded` event handler in the `OnLoaded` function and that worked. But I'm still curious why I can't remove it in the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* implement a finalizer to unregister from events because you cannot control when a finalizer is called. It's the garbage collector that decides when to call it.

If you want to unregister from event handlers that are hooked up to events of *other* elements, the `Unloaded` event would be a good place to do this in. You could register the handlers in the `Loaded` event and unregister them on `Unloaded`.

There is however no need to unregister from events of the object itself. You only need to unregister when the publisher of an event lives longer than the subscriber. This is to avoid memory leaks. If the publisher and the subscriber is the same object, you will never leak.